# How to get current pose for DENSO VS060

Tags: moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried to get current pose of DENSO VS060 after executing command below
roslaunch denso_launch denso_vs060_moveit_demo_simulation.launch

What I did in python was

```
group = MoveGroupCommander("manipulator")
temp_pose=group.get_current_pose()
```

Then I saw error message

```
time is not initialized. Have you called init_node()?
```

So I used the command below.

```
rospy.init_node("move_group")
```

Then RViz freezed.

Would you please tell me how to get current pose of robot?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/112871/how-to-get-current-pose-for-denso-vs060/) by [wyasuda](https://answers.ros.org/users/10211/wyasuda/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-12-23

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [wyasuda](https://answers.ros.org/users/10211/wyasuda/) on 2013-12-24**:
Thank you!
Now I understand that I made stupid mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What happens when you use a different name for your node? `move_group` is already used by MoveIt.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2013-12-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1